# How to return a JSONObject as a String in swift?

Tags: ios, json, string, swift

I would like to create a `new object` called `RegisterIn`, the target of the object is to generate a `json` object as dictionary and return as a String

Here is my code

```
public class RegisterIn {

    private var a : String = ""         //required
    private var b: String = ""          //required
    private var c: String = ""          //required
    private var d: Int =  0             //required

    private let BD_a : String = "a"
    private let BD_b : String = "b"
    private let BD_c : String = "c"
    private let BD_d : String = "d"

    init(a: String, b: String, c: String, d: Int) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
    }

    func getJSONObject() {
        let jsonDic : [String: AnyObject] = [
            BD_a: a,
            BD_b: b,
            BD_c: c,
            BD_d: d
        ]
        do {
            let jsonObject = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject( jsonDic, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func toString() {
        return String(getJSONObject())      <- this line occur error
    }
}
```

At function `getJSONObject`, I think it return a `jsonObject as [String: AnyObject]`. In my `ViewController`, I want to assign it to a `Label.text`, it always

[image]

my `ViewController`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var jsonLabel: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let a = RegisterIn.init(a: "123", b: "456", c: "789", d: 00000)

    jsonLabel.text = a
}
```

I think I have to change some code in RegisterIn class, really need some help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you never returned a string from `getJSONObject()`, try

```
func getJSONObject() -> String? {
    let jsonDic : [String: AnyObject] = [
        BD_a: a,
        BD_b: b,
        BD_c: c,
        BD_d: d
    ]
    do {
        let jsonObject = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject( jsonDic, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)

        return NSString(data: jsonObject, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
        return nil
    }
}

func toString() {
    return getJSONObject() //to be more correct, but this function is sort of redundant, just call getJSONObject directly, but up to you  whats the best
}
```

Comment: This is only half of the problem. The line `jsonLabel.text = a` if the other half.

Comment: ah right, just need `jsonLabel.text = a.toString()` i guess, but i find it strange its actually hitting the function then, maybe the toString is somehow implied with some swift magic

Comment: Don't you mean `jsonLabel.text = a.getJSONObject()`?

Comment: BTW - `getJSONObject` is a terrible name for a function that returns a String.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It may be

```
"let jsonObject = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject( jsonDic, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)"
```

has problem.
    You can make options with `null` for the replace the `PrettyPrinted`.
    `"options:[]`)"